# Mapping Xbox 360 (wired) controller buttons on SuperGNES

Tags: usb, usb-peripherals, game-controllers, 3.2-honeycomb

I'm trying to map A & B buttons in the SuperGNES emulator (on ACER A500 running Android 3.2) but it seems that A & B buttons are mapped as "back" action by default on Android. Is there any way to bypass or change this configuration so I can use those buttons?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is related to [SuperGNES](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblezapgames.supergnes_lite&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiY29tLmJ1YmJsZXphcGdhbWVzLnN1cGVyZ25lc19saXRlIl0.) app.

I've tried other emulators like [SNESDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ca.halsafar.snesdroid&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNhLmhhbHNhZmFyLnNuZXNkcm9pZCJd) and [Animaonline SNES](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=animaonline.android.snes.emu&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImFuaW1hb25saW5lLmFuZHJvaWQuc25lcy5lbXUiXQ..) and voilà worked as a charm!